# How do you port project and issues from one Jira server to another?

Tags: jira

How do you port projects and issues from one Jira server to another ?
To complicate things, the source server is 6 and target is 7.

Answer (score 2):

If [official guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/migrating-jira-to-another-server-151126305.html) does not suite your needs, you have other option.

If you or your developers familiar with SQL/ETL you can migrate and transform your data from one database to another.
Of course, you should (partially) follow official guide in this case too.

P.S. I completed migration from JIRA to Redmine 3 years ago. It is complex, but possible.